# initialising ttk.Entry in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Basically I have 8 entries I want to create in a loop and store in a dictionary, with a string as key:

```
class foo:
    entries={}
    keys=[#some keys are here, type string]
    #do other stuff
    def create_entries(self):
        for key in keys:
            entries[key]=ttk.Entry(self.frame,text='sometext')
    #other stuff going on
    def assign(self):
        f=open('file.name','r').read()
        #do some fancy slicing to get the strings for the entries
        for key in keys:
            entries[key].insert(0,string)
```

now here it fails, stating that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'.
I guess this is because I have declared entries as an empty dictionary.
But if I declare it like this: `entries={'KEY':ttk.Entry}` still states there is no insert for 'NoneType'. And if I declare it like `entries={'KEY':ttk,Entry()}` it initalises an empty toplayer on start, but if I come to load my entries, it tells me again, there is no insert for 'NoneType'.

So I am kind of lost right now.. is it even possible to initialise entries into a dictionary and later on insert some text in them? Or do I have to stick with each entry as a "individual variable"?

minimum working example:
If I delete the prints in the read-function and uncomment the inserts, it tells me: 
`self.entries[key].insert(0,s)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

f = open('testfile.test', 'w')
f.write('A=non-relevant\nB=SomeFunnyStuff\nZ=MySecretCode:9128\n')
f.close()

class foo:
    main = tk.Tk
    frame = ttk.LabelFrame
    keys = ['A','B','Z']
    entries={}
    labels={}
    def read(self):
        f = open('testfile.test','r').read()
        for key in self.keys:
            first=key+'='
            if key != 'Z':
                i = self.keys.index(key)+1
                last='\n'+self.keys[i]+'='
                s=f.split(first)[1].split(last)[0]
                print(s)#self.entries[key].insert(0,s)
            else:
                s=f.split(first)[1]
                print(s)#self.entries[key].insert(0,s)


    def _quit(self):
        self.main.quit()
        self.main.destroy()
        exit()
    def run(self):
        self.main.mainloop()
    def __init__(self):
        #init window
        self.main = tk.Tk()
        self.main.title('Test')
        self.frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.main, text='Try it').grid(column=0,row=0)
        #init entries & labels
        c,r=0,0
        for key in self.keys:
            s = key+'='
            self.labels[key] = ttk.Label(self.frame, text=s).grid(column=c,row=r)
            c+=1
            self.entries[key] = ttk.Entry(self.frame,text=s).grid(column=c,row=r)
            r+=1
            c-=1
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='close',command=lambda:self._quit()).grid(column=0,row=r)

        self.read()
        print(self.entries.values())

t = foo()
t.run()
```

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: The code posted will not give you a `NoneType object has no attribute 'insert'` error. And yes, it's possible to use a dictionary, when used correctly.

Comment: @StephenRauch I added a minimum working example.

Comment: This code does not exhibit an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem:

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get#1101765) post the problem is with how I initialized the entries in my original code & the minimum example posted (not in the original post unfortunately..):
`self.entries[key] = ttk.Entry(self.frame,text=s).grid(column=c,row=r)` returns a `None` to the dictionary, as `.grid()` returns `None`

Initializing labels and entries first and then using grid in a separate line however works fine:

```
self.entries[key] = ttk.Entry(self.frame,text=s)
self.entries[key].grid(column=c,row=r)
```

That fixed it for me.